# SQL - Query using Join / Having / Subquery - How

Tags: sql, join, vbscript

Please suggest a sql query to fetch the

"list of students and corresponding subject in which student has same score , if the student has same score in more than one subject"

eg.

```
Student Subject Score
John    Science 80
John    Maths   80
John    English 80
John    French  80
Peter   Science 85
Peter   Maths   70
Peter   English 70
Peter   French  70
Mathews French  70

Expected Result :
John    Science
John    Maths
John    English
John    French
Peter   Maths
Peter   English
Peter   French
```

tried -

```
select person , subject where person in 
( select person , score , count(score) group by person , score having count(score) > 1 )
```

but in this "Peter Science" appears , which is not required.

Please assist.

Thanks

Comment: Your outer query does not have a `FROM <tableName>` clause..

Comment: Are you allowed to use ranking functions?

Comment: @Meherzad - have just given an idea of what I was trying, its not the exact query. You could look at the problem statement and suggest a solution.

Comment: @ta.speot.is sure , can you help in that. I am using vbscript to fetch rows from an acceess database and then proceed with my further calculations. As long as I can get the desired result any means is justified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select person , subject 
from table t
  join 
     ( select person , score , count(score) 
       from table
       group by person , score having count(score) > 1 
     ) foo
       on t.person = foo.person
 where t.person = foo.person 
   and t.score = foo.score
```

The reason your query didn't work (aside from not including a table):
Your inner query was selecting the students and scores that match your criteria. But your outer query was selecting *everything* for all students who matched the criteria, which is why "peter science" was being included. So, you needed to limit the results in your outer query to only those that match all of your criteria.

Comment: . Thanks. Very fast reply. Just a little further help.
using vbscript , to connect to accesss - any modifications in syntax.
trying out in access first.

Comment: I'm not an Access expert, but I don't _think_ any modification in syntax for the query should be required.  It's standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell us what RDBMS are you using. But this should work everywhere:

```
select 
    t.*
from <tableName> t
join (
    select
        student, score
    from <tableName>
    group by 
        student, score
    having count(*)>1 
) x
on  t.student=x.student
and t.score=x.score
```

Btw you're missing `FROM <tableName>` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
select student, subject
from Person 
where student + cast(score as varchar(20)) in 
(   
    select student + cast(score as varchar(20)) from Person group by student,score having count(score) > 1 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this goal self-joining table like in example:

```
SELECT
  t.Student,
  t.Subject,
  t.Score
FROM Table1 AS t
  JOIN 
    (
        SELECT Student, Score FROM Table1 GROUP BY Student, Score HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS t1 ON t.Student = t1.Student AND t.Score = t1.Score
```

Full example with test data and created table you can find here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61f02/8